# How do I make a tiny 'shadow' under an image, like this one?

Tags: html, css, templates

http://www.deviantart.com/#order=9&q=sun

As you can see, each picture...underneath it...it has a little tiny shadow around the edges.

How can this be done with a variable size image? (css)

Comment: BTW, DA is not doing it dynamically, it has a background image with known size: http://sh.deviantart.net/shadow/x/142/170/logo3.png . This is viable when you have many images but limited sizes.

Comment: @AUSteve - Not really. If you look at the source, the size of the shadow is coded in the url - it is determined at the server. You cannot use this technique to add shadows to a resizable element.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the answers above, let me explain how devianart does it ..

they have an image generator, that creates the shadow image at anysize they want ..

You can see the background shadow of an image at http://sh.deviantart.net/shadow/x/113/150/logo3.png
now playing around with the url and altering the 113 and 150 creates new images of arbitrary size which they use ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-shadow`, but it wouldn't work cross browser: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by shifting a background image behind the original image. There are quite a few tutorials on the internet:
[Tutorial 1](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-drop-shadows/)
[Tutorial 2](http://www.alexallied.com/tutorials/learn-how-to-apply-shadow-automatically-to-an-image-using-css)